# GCP - Loadbalancer pricing when using nginx ingress controller

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

How to calculate the pricing for GCP loadbalancers when using nginx ingress controller?

Right now I have 1 Ingress host and a single rule for prod website. But I want to launch another for internal services both gitlab, jenkins.

Is the cost calculated based on the number of `path's` we have in ingress? Or number of load balancers like AWS? I'm assuming each `rule` in GCP calculator means a `path` in ingress.

Comment: Hi SO is for programming questions, e.g. use of GCP APIs, for server setup you should post on Webmasters or Server Fault sites. For pricing is always best to ask provider the directly...

Comment: Are you using GKE?

Comment: I think nginx ingress runs inside your GKE cluster. So you're not using GCP load balancer at all? You can check the google ones in web console to see if there's any listed.

Comment: I see them listed under GCP -> Network services -> Load balancing. Is nginx ingress supposed to not list under GCP console? How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is the GCP pricing [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) you can calculate the LB pricing here. I think pricing calculated here without nginx ingress controller.